# WerFault System Error Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, system-error

Hello i am facing the following problem:

After i reinstalled `windows 7` and `VStudio 2017 Community Preview` i was faced with the `WerFault`. error when trying to run a project:
[image]

After searching for a solution i have reinstalled the VC++ Redistributables and VStudio to no avail.Is there any solution for this?

**P.S**: This error persists on any type of project.Initially i thought it was because i was using .netcore 2.1 but it has nothing to do with that.

Comment: What problem was reinstalling the OS supposed to solve?  Ensure that Windows Update has finished updating the machine, it delivers the ucrtbase.dll component.

Comment: I didn't say i reinstalled the os after i had this problem but before.This problem is somehow a consequence of the fresh install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by uninstalling `VC++ Redistributables (2017)` and installing the `2015` version.It worked like a charm.